# Hadoop Configuration in Local Machine

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am very new to Hadoop and Hbase. I am very confused with the configuration details. I need to create tables using Java API in Hbase. I dont have the software in my local machine, I am connecting to my server using Putty. Now my question is, with the software in my local machine can I write programs to communicate with a remote server. Please, can any one clear my doubt as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the zookeeper IP and proceed your logic. For examples and CRUD operations, refer Hbase Definite Guide book.
Here is the Sample code to create table by hitting the zookeeper IP from remote pc.

```
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.***.*.**"); // Zookeeper IP
    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
    HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor();
    desc.setName(Bytes.toBytes("SampleTable"));
    HColumnDescriptor family = new HColumnDescriptor("col1".getBytes()); //Column family name
    desc.addFamily(family);
    admin.createTable(desc);
```

Comment: Do ZooKeeper IP is enough or do we need to use any Master IP Address, i am really confused with regional server and  zookeeper server?. CAn you please guide me through this

Comment: Zookeeper IP is enough to access the Hbase remotely from Java. Zookeeper Will take care of connecting to Hbase Master.Regional Server are the Collections of HRegions which will act as a storage region for the table(You can see that in HBASE web UI). For more Info Kindly refer Hbase Definite Guide book.